# Best way to learn about Client-Side Rendering with JSLink

Tags: jslink

I figured out that using JSLink can lift SharePoint onto a new level. But unfortunately I am completely lost on really understanding it.

I feel like just copy pasting code samples does not help me, also because (obviously) everybody has it's own style of writing code.

Is there any official guideline or tutorial? How do I know which functions do exist? How do I know how to address a specific column/field? I have a basic understanding about JavaScript, so I don't need to learn about variables or a if... else statements, but I struggle to bring JSLink into context with it.

Comment: Read this http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately CSR has no official documentation yet. You can have a look on following stuff by **Andrei Markeev**

[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms + KnockoutJs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888923/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p)

[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms + Layout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039724/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p)

**Andrei Markeev** has a tool to make CSR development easier.

[SharePoint CSR Live Edit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)

You can also have a look on [iCSR](https://gist.github.com/iansheridan/62a53a8675ad3f415e5e) by **Danny Engelman**

Comment: To add to this answer, **Ross Bradbrook** has a nice article introducing CSR: http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/client-side-rendering-2013/. **Muawiyah Shannak** posted a list of CSR samples which may help: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a